# SSIS Package Configuration Error "One or more required parameters have not been assigned values"

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS 2012 package that contains Execute Package Tasks.  Each Execute Package Task calls a child package.  Each child package can also run independently so it has its own package level parameter configuration.

When I execute the parent package within Business Intelligence Development Studio I get the error "One or more required parameters have not been assigned values".  This error applies to the child package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter values defined on the child packages at design time weren't being used at run time.  I needed to define parameter values at the parent package or project level and then pass these values to the child packages.

The bindings between the parent package / project parameters and the child package parameters can be set on each Execute Package Task by right clicking on the Execute Package Task and selecting 'Edit' > 'Parameter bindings'.

Answer (score 0):

When using package parameters in child packages, it is not allowed to set them as REQUIRED. Because then the child package expects that this parameters must be set by the calling package (parent package).

The explanation of the property **REQUIRED** for parameters (copied from Visual Studio):
"Requires that a value, other than the design default, is specified before the package can execute."